# Recommendations around cleaning-up/deleting files present in Tomcat temp Dir

Tags: java, spring, file, tomcat6

What are some of the best practices around deleting/cleaning up files present inside temp dir on Tomcat-6. The files are images created by charting packages, numerous files created by various applications deployed on the web server. The required lifetime of the file is the duration of a user session. I would appreciate if anyone provide recommendations/pros-cons regarding best practices related to this - whether i should be looking at HttpSession Listener, Servlet Context Listener, cleaning up on startup, Spring based approach etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no "best practices" for this.  There are just methods that work or don't work, **depending on the application requirements**.

And the key requirement is the required lifetime of the file.  Is it required for just the duration of a request?  For the duration of a user session?  For some other period; e.g. until the user "collects" it?

Comment: Required lifetime of the file is the duration of a user session.

Comment: In that case, you should probably use an HttpSessionListener to clean up the temporary files, and some kind of backstop ... like a daemon thread or startup task to delete all files older than a certain age.